# Check output of ARPingResult?

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

I want to check the output of the ARPing result, it should be converted into a string so it can later on go into regex. Any Idea how to do that???

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import subprocess
import os
import re
print('\033[1;36;47m starting')

os.system("clear")
os.system("figlet ARP Scan")
pattern_one = '\d\d\d.\d\d\d.\d.\d'
pattern_two = '\d\d\d.\d\d\d.\d.\d\d'
#192.18`.0.0/24

def actualscan():
    result = scapy.arping("192.168.0.0/24")
    result_two = str(result)
    subresult = subprocess.check_output(result_two)
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("figlet ARP Scan")

    return subresult

def reresult(actualscanresult, pattern_one, pattern_two):
    pat_one_result = re.findall(pattern_one, actualscanresult)
    pat_two_result = re.findall(pattern_two, actualscanresult)

    return pat_one_result, pat_two_result

actualscanresult = actualscan()
exsea1, exsea2 = reresult(actualscanresult, pattern_one, pattern_two)

print(exsea1)
print(exsea2)
```

Comment: Hello, did the answer help to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Scapy's `arping` function is setup to print out the results. You're looking for a list containing the results. Here's how to get that.

Let's copy-and-edit the `ARPingResult` class for our new purpose. (It's really just adding the `return data` statement at the end of `show`:

```
from scapy.plist import SndRcvList

class ARPingResultData(SndRcvList):
    def __init__(self,
                 res=None,  # type: Optional[Union[_PacketList[QueryAnswer], List[QueryAnswer]]]  # noqa: E501
                 name="ARPing",  # type: str
                 stats=None  # type: Optional[List[Type[Packet]]]
                 ):
        SndRcvList.__init__(self, res, name, stats)

    def show(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # type: (*Any, **Any) -> None
        """
        list discovered MAC addresses.
        """

        data = list()
        padding = 0

        for s, r in self.res:
            manuf = conf.manufdb._get_short_manuf(r.src)
            manuf = "unknown" if manuf == r.src else manuf
            padding = max(padding, len(manuf))
            data.append((r[Ether].src, manuf, r[ARP].psrc))

# We no longer want a printout.
#        for src, manuf, psrc in data:
#            print("  %-17s %-*s %s" % (src, padding, manuf, psrc))
        return data
```

Note that the data is provided as a list of 3-tuples.

Now, we want to make a new version of `arping` that uses this edited `ARPingResultData`:

```
_arp_cache = conf.netcache.new_cache("arp_cache", 120)

def arping(net, timeout=2, cache=0, verbose=None, **kargs):
    # type: (str, int, int, Optional[int], **Any) -> Tuple[ARPingResult, PacketList] # noqa: E501
    """Send ARP who-has requests to determine which hosts are up
arping(net, [cache=0,] [iface=conf.iface,] [verbose=conf.verb]) -> None
Set cache=True if you want arping to modify internal ARP-Cache"""
    if verbose is None:
        verbose = conf.verb
    ans, unans = srp(
        Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / ARP(pdst=net),
        verbose=verbose,
        filter="arp and arp[7] = 2",
        timeout=timeout,
        iface_hint=net,
        **kargs
    )
    ans = ARPingResultData(ans.res)

    if cache and ans is not None:
        for pair in ans:
            _arp_cache[pair[1].psrc] = pair[1].hwsrc
    if ans is not None and verbose:
        ans.show()
    return ans, unans
```

Note that this provides a list of 2-tuples. The first are answered responses, and the second are unanswered. (In our code change above, we didn't parse the second into a list since that's not what you asked for.)

To use it, just run it like before, but keep the output in a variable:

`results = arping('192.168.0.0/24')`

Now, all you have to do is read that list of tuples by indexing the first part:

`results[0].show()`

Your results will look like this:

```
  [<mac-address> <manufacturer> <ip-address>,
   <mac-address> <manufacturer> <ip-address>,
   <mac-address> <manufacturer> <ip-address>,
...
   <mac-address> <manufacturer> <ip-address>]
```

(I've hidden the mac-addresses, manufacturers, and ip-addresses gathered from my network to protect the guilty.)

Now that you have a list of tuples, you can easily parse out the fields you need.